# I need the dimensions for the RPI Zero and RPI3

Tags: pi-3, pi-zero

I am needing help with the dimensions of the raspberry pi. Namely,  the zero and the 3b. I would prefer diagrams. All I've been finding online is conflicting measurements. I've gone to raspberrypi.org, and didn't find anything. I would prefer something from newark/element14. Perhaps I'm not wording things correctly, I'm not sure.

The reason I need this info,  is because I am making a High Altitude Balloon project,  and need to design the enclosure,  but without the measurements,  it does me no good. I don't have access to accurate enough equipment that helps me with these measurements.

Comment: You're going to design the enclosure without having one in hand? They have at least two manufacturers.

Comment: Unfortunately,  yes. Every time I try to get a PiZero,  they're sold out. It's quite annoying actually. I honestly,  don't think that the measurements would be too far off from either of the 2 manufacturers. Considering that the raspberry pi foundation designs the units,  it would be logical. I do know the standoff holes are off considerably by tenths of a millimeter.

Comment: And buying a prefab case won't work? They have plenty of custom fit ones on Adafruit

Comment: No,  it won't work. The enclosure is for a High Altitude Balloon Project. I am using 3 PIZ,  one PI3B, multiple sensors,  and sending other unrelated payload up into the atmosphere.

Comment: In stock now https://www.adafruit.com/product/2885

Comment: Lol,  thanks... I might mention,  that part of the balance of acquisition of the PIZ also hinges on other financial burdens. Either they're sold out when I have the money,  and have them when I don't.

Comment: <shameless plug>I think the Guys doing the RPi [blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/) would love to hear more about your project in the future when it, _ahem_ gets of the ground! 8-)</shameless plug>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to locate diagrams for both the Pi 3b and the Pi zero from very reputable sources, one being the Pi site itself for the pi3b, which can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/mechanicalspecB+.png), the image was taken from [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-model-b-plus/). Furthermore a diagram for the Pi zero may be found [here](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/102-79288-1-233325/Raspberry+Pi+Zero+-+Technical+Drawing.png), which is from element 14 which is a rather reputable source in my opinion, and that image was taken from [here](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-79288/l/raspberry-pi-zero-technical-details).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the exact mechanical drawings for the Pi 3 and Zero [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/mechanical/README.md) on the Raspberry Pi Foundation's official site. This pages includes links to both of the models you asked for, as well as the one for the 1B+. Curiously, it's missing all other models (1A, 1A+, 1B, and 2B).